# Creating responsive grid based web page

Tags: html, css

I want to display static naive bar in top and rest entire page into grid of 6 column and increasing rows.

css:

```
http://grids.heroku.com/grid.css?column_width=182&column_amount=6&gutter_width=5
```

Here is html:

```
<div class=container_6>
   <div class=grid_5>
   </div>    
 </div>
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/vpqvrxhn/1/

Why display page still looks empty?

I am following this doc : http://1200px.com/

Comment: Probably because you have no content in it?!

Comment: @fatman: thanks, but I put color, so i was expecting empty grid with color

Comment: color affects the text color! put background-color

Comment: because container's height is 0px....

Comment: I've set 20px height to container try - http://jsfiddle.net/vpqvrxhn/3/

Comment: @MaryMelody: thanks, i appreciate your update. I used it here: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/vpqvrxhn/4/, actually it should look like this http://1200px.com/ for 6 column, but it appears entire red

Comment: @user2129623 Try 6 Grids Container - http://jsfiddle.net/vpqvrxhn/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why display page still looks empty?

Because your container's height is 0px. You must set some `height` to your Container's Grids.

I've created 6 Grids Container for you as [1200px.com](http://1200px.com/) for 6 columns - **[TRY THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vpqvrxhn/10/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class=container_6>
   <div class=grid_1></div>   
   <div class=grid_1></div>
   <div class=grid_1></div>
   <div class=grid_1></div>
   <div class=grid_1></div>
   <div class=grid_1></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* ---------- Containers ---------- */

.container_6 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1122px;
}
.grid_1 {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height: 300px;
}
```

### [EDITED]

**As per your comment:**

> I want entire screen to be divided into grid of 6 column and 5 row. It
>   should be responsive to any device. IS that possible? – @user2129623

### **TRY** - **[THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vpqvrxhn/12/)**

I've set `padding: 5px 0px;` and `height: 20%;` to `.container_6` to divided the entire screen into grid of 6 columns and 5 rows and you can adjust the padding as you want.

Comment: I want entire screen to be divided into grid of 6 column and 5 row. It should be responsive to any device. IS that possible??

Comment: thanks a lot. It's awwsome. but as I can see it is hirizontally responsible but when we trace the window vertically it does not behave responsible.

Comment: @user2129623 It's alway 100% height of the screen and divided into grid of 6 column and 5 row... try to re-size the window vertically.

Comment: yeah it is responsible top to bottom, but when we resize the window left to right, the grid size does not change.

Comment: It's because in your fiddle there's fixed width of 1122px and there is no css @media queries... Please check your fiddle...

Comment: thanks, it's ok. but is it possible so that we can make is responsible for width too. for my info?

Comment: I tried it by making `min-width: 100%;` , but no h elp

Comment: Sorry about it, but the grid system you're using have their own fixed width of 182px (.grid_1), If you want to set 100% width then you've to change the grids width as well. May I change it for you... Only for 6 columns and 5 rows, If you want to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60443/discussion-between-user2129623-and-mary-melody).